# Hibernate java.lang.ClassCastException: _$$_javassist_856 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy when using Websphere Shared Library

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere, websphere-8, javassist

**Websphere 8.0.0.11**

**Hibernate 4.2.21.Final**

I have found many questions about this same problem but none of them worked for me.

If I deploy the application in Websphere it works OK.

However we have defined a shared library that contains all the third party libraries (spring, hibernate, javassist, etc) so that our WARs are thinner.

This way during deployment we associate our thin WAR against that Websphere shared library.

The point is that when we deploy the application this way the `ClassCastException Hibernate exception _$$_javassist_856 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy` is thrown.

I have checked the loaded jars in the websphere console and can only see one javassist jar (3.18.1-GA)  in the classpath.

Why could this be happening?

**UPDATE**

I have also tried using PARENT_FIRST and PARENT_LAST class loading.

**UPDATE 2**

I just found out that Websphere is loading its own javassist jar:

```
URL location = ProxyFactory.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation(); 
logger.info("{}", location);
```

It prints: `file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/javassist.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying pretty much everything I found on S.O. without any success I decided to **downgrade Hibernate to version 4.1.12.Final**. This is the maximum 4.x version compatible with Websphere 8.x.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Javassist leaves traces in its generated code. With Javassist on the class path twice, its classes are loaded twice. Two types are however only equal if they have the same name **and** are loaded by the same class loader. In your case, the generated class resolves its Javassist dependeny to a type that is loaded by your application class loader while your code is casting the instance to the Javassist type that is loaded by the Websphere class loader (or the other way around).

Are you sharing any Hibernate dependencies between applications? Try to not use any shared libraries related to Hibernate in your application to avoid this.

Comment: Hi Rafael, thank you for answering. Yes we are sharing a number of libraries defined in a websphere shared library to lighten our heavy wars. So far, we had Spring 4.x + Hibernate 3.6, and everything run smoothly. Websphere's Javassist must've been compatible with the one in our shared library. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a good solution to this...

Comment: What you can do is that you can shade your dependency to place it in a different namespace.